# SSIS flat file exists -- script task fails when no file exists

Tags: c#, ssis

I am working in SSIS (BIDS) under SQL Server 2008 R2.  I have a package that imports a flat file to an OLE DB.  Before the import data flow task, I have a script task (written in C#, not VB) to test if the file exists.  I have 2 precedence constraints off of the script task.  The first one is my success path (Evaluation Operation = 'Constraint' and Value = 'Success'), which goes to a data flow task.  The second one is my failure path (Evaluation Operation = 'Constraint' and Value = 'Failure'), which goes to a dummy task (a SQL task), just so that the package doesn't fail when the file doesn't exist.

In debugging, I confirmed that, when the file exists, it goes all the way through the data flow task (as expected).  However, when the file doesn't exist, the package fails; in particular, it fails at the first step (i.e., the script task).  I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  Below is my code for the script task:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace ST_2f8cf79f6fe0443b9c09c453433a0258.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        #region VSTA generated code
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

        public void Main()
        {
            if (File.Exists(Dts.Variables["PRC_file_path"].Value.ToString()))
            {
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
            else
            {
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You've asked a few questions about SSIS and this file existence: perhaps if this one doesn't solve your problem, backup and restate what you are trying to do, the assumptions about your implementation and then the specifics of what is not working. $.02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it's behaving exactly as it is supposed to; it fails the script if the file doesn't exist.

I would use a variable instead to report the existence of a file.

```
public void Main()
{ 
string targetfile = Dts.Variables["PRC_file_path"].Value.ToString();

 if (File.Exists(targetfile))
            {
                Dts.Variables["file_exists"].Value = true;
            }
            else
            {
                 Dts.Variables["file_exists"].Value = false;
            }
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

You want the script itself to succeed, unless it encounters an error.

Better yet would be:

```
public void Main()
{ 
string targetfile = Dts.Variables["PRC_file_path"].Value.ToString();
  try{
 if (File.Exists(targetfile))
            {
                Dts.Variables["file_exists"].Value = true;
            }
            else
            {
                 Dts.Variables["file_exists"].Value = false;
            }

     Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
     }
 catch (Exception Ex)
     {
     Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
     }
}
```

Edit:

Forgot to mention that you need to switch the precedence constraints from CONSTRAINT to Expression and CONSTRAINT, where the expression evaluates the @file_exists variable.  You should have two success paths, one with the variabled evaluating to true and the other to false.

Comment: I don't think I understand the color change on tasks in the debugger.  When a task becomes red, does that mean that an error was encountered (e.g., something is wrong with my script)?  Or, does it mean that the Failure path will be followed?

Comment: It can mean either.  With your code it meant the latter, but the task failure was causing the package to terminate.  In my code it means that an error was encountered causing the code to exit.  We consider it bad form to have tasks fail by design in our organization.  Better to reserve "Failure" for unhandled errors.

Comment: I think there is a missing ; after the targetfile variable assignment.  Also, SSIS is throwing a warning that True and False do not exist in the current context.  How do I fix that?

Comment: You are correct, and `true` and `false` should be lower-case, which will resolve that issue.

Comment: My package is failing even when the file exists.  I created a file_exists Boolean variable (default to False).  I used the script in your latest post (the one with try-catch).  I set up 2 precedence constraints (where Evaluation operation = 'Expression and Constraint' and Value = 'Success').  On the first one, Expression = '@file_exists==True'.  On the second one Expression = '@file_exists==False'.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could try mapping to integers instead of a boolean.  Set file_exists to 1 or 0 instead of true or false.

Comment: I figured out my error.  In the Script Task Editor, I had to set ReadWriteVariables = User::file_exists.